# How do I replace a certain line in /etc/passwd file?

Tags: bash-scripting, ubuntu-20.04

So, I'm trying to make a script that disables the root account by changing the

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

with

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/sbin/nologin`.

Is there a command that lets me do this? Thanks.

Comment: you can try `sed` comand with something like this (not tested): `sed -i 's/\/root:\/bin\/bash/\/root:\/sbin\/nologin/g' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially trying to change the shell of the user `root`. There is a command for this: `chsh` (change shell).

```
$ sudo chsh --shell /sbin/nologin root
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!